# how to display a dyanamically generated jtree or tree model in ui

Tags: java, jsp

how to display a dyanamically generated jtree or tree model in ui ?is there any tree structure in jsp or any simple tree model in javascript or jquery please suggest.I searched in web there some 
jquery tree examples are there but is there any easy way to display jtree in ui?please give your valuable suggestions

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be to encode your tree structure as a JSON response and pass it to some JQuery plugin to do the rendering.